# Preg_match for all special characters, password checking

Tags: php, preg-match, special-characters

Ok so I am writing a password checker for our password policy which requires 3 of the 4 major classifications. Where I'm having problems with is the special character match.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
private function PasswordRequirements($ComplexityCount) {
    $Count = 0;
    if(preg_match("/\d/", $this->PostedData['password']) > 0) {
        $Count++;
    }
    if(preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $this->PostedData['password']) > 0) {
        $Count++;
    }
    if(preg_match("/[a-z]/", $this->PostedData['password']) > 0) {
        $Count++;
    }
    // This is where I need help
    if(preg_match("/[~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=\[\]{}\|\\:;\"\'<,>.]/", $this->PostedData['password']) > 0) {
        $Count++;
    }

    if($Count >= $ComplexityCount) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So basically what I'm doing is checking the string for each case, numbers, uppercase, lowercase, and special characters. We don't have any restrictions on any special character and I also need unicode characters. Does the \W work in this case or would that also include numbers again? I can't find great documentation on \W so I'm unclear on this part.

Does anyone know of a easy regexp that would cover all special characters and unicode characters that does not include numbers and letters?

Anyone is free to use this as I think more than a few people have been looking for this.

Comment: Here's a great page that explain some of your speculations: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This pattern would allow all characters that's not a digit or a-Z.

```
[^\da-zA-Z]
```

Regarding the `\W` it's a negated `\w`, which is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Thus will `\W` be all characters that's not an english letter, digit or an underscore.

As I mentioned as a comment [this is a great resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for learning regex. And here's a good site to [test the regex](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: I'm slapping myself up the head. Thank you so much I didn't even think of doing the reverse of the previous checks. And thank you for that resource that will come in handy. - Jeff

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to match on special characters

```
preg_match('/[\'\/~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|;:"\<\>,\.\?\\\]/', $input)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the POSIX character class `[[:punct:]]` for the 'special' characters:

```
<?php
$regex = '[[:punct:]]';

if (preg_match('/'.$regex.'/', 'somepas$', $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
?>
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => $
)
```